# Creating a loop with character variables on R - for two-sample t.test

Tags: r, loops, rstudio

I am looking to do multiple two sample t.tests in R. 
I want to test 50 indicators that have two levels. So at first I used :

```
t.test(m~f)
   Welch Two Sample t-test
   data:  m by f
   t = 2.5733, df = 174.416, p-value = 0.01091
   alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
   95 percent confidence interval:
   0.05787966 0.43891600
   sample estimates:
    mean in group FSS mean in group NON-FSS 
        0.8344209             0.5860231
```

Here m corresponds to the first indicator I want to test m =Debt.to.equity.ratio.
Here is a list of all the indicators I need to test :

```
print (indicators)
 [1] "Debt.to.equity.ratio"                                   "Deposits.to.loans"                                     
 [3] "Deposits.to.total.assets"                               "Gross.loan.portfolio.to.total.assets"                  
 [5] "Number.of.active.borrowers"                             "Percent.of.women.borrowers"                            
 [7] "Number.of.loans.outstanding"                            "Gross.loan.portfolio"                                  
 [9] "Average.loan.balance.per.borrower"                      "Average.loan.balance.per.borrower...GNI.per.capita"    
[11] "Average.outstanding.balance"                            "Average.outstanding.balance...GNI.per.capita"          
[13] "Number.of.depositors"                                   "Number.of.deposit.accounts"                            
[15] "Deposits"                                               "Average.deposit.balance.per.depositor"                 
[17] "Average.deposit.balance.per.depositor...GNI.per.capita" "Average.deposit.account.balance"                       
[19] "Average.deposit.account.balance...GNI.per.capita"       "Return.on.assets"                                      
[21] "Return.on.equity"                                       "Operational.self.sufficiency"                          
[23] "FSS"                                                    "Financial.revenue..assets"                             
[25] "Profit.margin"                                          "Yield.on.gross.portfolio..nominal."                    
[27] "Yield.on.gross.portfolio..real."                        "Total.expense..assets"                                 
[29] "Financial.expense..assets"                              "Provision.for.loan.impairment..assets"                 
[31] "Operating.expense..assets"                              "Personnel.expense..assets"                             
[33] "Administrative.expense..assets"                         "Operating.expense..loan.portfolio"                     
[35] "Personnel.expense..loan.portfolio"                      "Average.salary..GNI.per.capita"                        
[37] "Cost.per.borrower"                                      "Cost.per.loan"                                         
[39] "Borrowers.per.staff.member"                             "Loans.per.staff.member"                                
[41] "Borrowers.per.loan.officer"                             "Loans.per.loan.officer"                                
[43] "Depositors.per.staff.member"                            "Deposit.accounts.per.staff.member"                     
[45] "Personnel.allocation.ratio"                             "Portfolio.at.risk...30.days"                           
[47] "Portfolio.at.risk...90.days"                            "Write.off.ratio"                                       
[49] "Loan.loss.rate"                                         "Risk.coverage"
```

Instead of changing the indicator name each time in the t.test, I would like to create a loop that will do it automatically and calculate the p.value. I've tried creating a loop but can't make it work due to the nature of the variables = characters.

I would really appreciate any tips on how to go forward!
Thank you very much !

Best 
Morgan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are doing the regression of each indicator against the same f.

In that case, you can try something like:

```
  p_vals = NULL;
  for(this_indicator in indicators)
    {
    this_formula = paste(c(this_indicator, "f"), collapse="~");
    res = t.test(as.formula(this_formula));
    p_vals = c(p_vals, res$p.value);
    }
```

One comment, however: are you doing any multiplicity adjustment for these p-values? Given the large of tests you are doing, there is a good chance you will be showered with false positives.

Comment: Hi Gvrocha, Thank you for your quick answer, I just started using R. I've tried the code but it still doesn't seem to work. Yes I'm using the bonferroni adjustment but my main issue is : I have a large set of data with all these different indicators, one of the columns : called FSS here, which I renamed previously f, has two levels : NON FSS and FSS. I would like to do a two-sample test betw the 2 groups for all the indicators. However I would like to create a loop to go through all the different indicators to test if the difference is significant between the two levels! Thank you very much !

Comment: I've tried to test for each indicators if there is a significant different with FSS and NON FSS ( variable X ) and modified your code like this :                 `> p_vals = NULL;
> for(Capita.asset.ratio in data)
+ {
+     this_formula = paste(c(Capita.asset.ratio ~ X));
+     res = t.test(as.formula(this_formula));
+     p_vals = c(p_vals, res$p.value);
+ }`                                                                                                                  but I still can't manage to test every variable it only tests Capita.asset.ratio...